# Mux implementation details in FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx

im currently taking a look at a xilinx documentation
I would like to understand in the image of the FPGA Slices, is it possible to configure the Muxes to be 2;1, 4:1, 8:1 etc..

Source: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug474_7Series_CLB.pdf
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you using a high-level language (VHDL/Verilog)? The tools can easily synthesize any size mux with the available building blocks. You normally don't need to worry about the details.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the multiplexers shown in the diagram are for configuring the CLB to do a particular type of function - logic, registered logic, register, etc. These mux settings are static, configured by the bitstream. They aren't accessible by user logic.

Multiplexers you implement will usually be synthesized into LUTs. They may also use the muxes that are shown as shaded, driven by LUTs or AX, BX, CX and DX from other CLBs to extend the width of a logic function for example.

A way to gain understanding of how the toolchain renders logic is to compile a design (synthesize, implement) and then choose 'Open Implemented Design' and open a Device window. Here, you can zoom in and see what the tool did to your logic at the CLB level.

Most of the time you don't care. Sometimes, you want to see how many layers of delay got inserted if you encounter a timing-critical path.

There is also a Schematic view that shows this.

Comment: How do i use the muxes to implement Adder logic?

Comment: also thanks for the details

Comment: How to make an adder? Enter it in Verilog or VHDL and let the synthesizer figure it out. If you’re curious about how it renders in CLBs, use Device View.